# R Plotly changing a 3D plot camera in code

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

I am currently trying to plot subplots of differents datas.

I need the code to plot the different figures exactly the way I want them without me having to modify them after.

I have a problem with a 3D plot overlapped with the other plot in a subplot, as you can see here :

[image: Figure generated]

I need to manualy resset it (by using the zoom, pan and turntable rotation of the plotly display) in order to have it the way I like, that way (approximately) :

[image: Figure that I want]

How can I automatize this process through the code ? I have been reading documentation for a while and can't find anything that might do the job.

Thank you very much !

You can find the code I am using below :

```
dataresults1ab <- read.table("./Datas/dataresults1ab.txt")
dataresults1c <- read.table("./Datas/dataresults1c.txt")
dataresults1d <- read.table("./Datas/dataresults1d.txt")

Fig1a <- {plot_ly(dataresults1ab,x= ~time,y= ~N1,name = "Species 1", type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N2, name = "Species 2", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N3, name = "Species 3", mode="lines")%>%
   layout(title="Time course of the abundances of three species competing for three ressources",xaxis=list(title="Time (days)",range=c(0,200)),yaxis=list(title="Species abundances",range=c(0,50)))}

Fig1b<-{plot_ly(dataresults1ab, x = ~N1, y = ~N2, z = ~N3, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines")%>%
   layout(title="The corresponding limit cycle",
          scene=list(xaxis=list(title="Species 1",range=c(0,50)),
                     yaxis=list(title="Species 2",range=c(0,50)),
                     zaxis=list(title="Species 3",range=c(0,50)),
                     camera=list(up=list(0,0.5,0.5))))}

Fig1c <- {plot_ly(dataresults1c,x= ~time,y= ~N1,name = "Species 1", type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N2, name = "Species 2", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N3, name = "Species 3", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N4, name = "Species 4", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N5, name = "Species 5", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N6, name = "Species 6", mode="lines") %>%
   layout(title="Small-amplitude oscilations of six species on three ressources",xaxis=list(title="Time (days)",range=c(0,15000)),yaxis=list(title="Species abundances",range=c(0,70)))}

Fig1d <- {plot_ly(dataresults1d,x= ~time,y= ~N1,name = "Species 1", type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N2, name = "Species 2", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N3, name = "Species 3", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N4, name = "Species 4", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N5, name = "Species 5", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N6, name = "Species 6", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N7, name = "Species 7", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N8, name = "Species 8", mode="lines") %>%
   add_trace(y= ~N9, name = "Species 9", mode="lines") %>%
   layout(title="Large-amplitude oscilations of nine species on three ressources",xaxis=list(title="Time (days)",range=c(0,3000)),yaxis=list(title="Species abundances",range=c(0,40)))}

Fig1 <- {subplot(Fig1a,Fig1b,Fig1c,Fig1d,nrows=2,margin=0.1,titleY=T,titleX = T)%>%
   layout(scene = list(domain = list(x = c(0.5,1), y = c(0.5,1))),
          showlegend=F,
          title="",
          annotations = list(list( 
            x = 0,  
            y = 1,  
            text = "a)",  
            xref = "paper",  
            yref = "paper",  
            xanchor = "center",  
            yanchor = "bottom",  
            showarrow = F
          ),  
          list( 
            x = 0.6,  
            y = 1,  
            text = "b)",  
            xref = "paper",  
            yref = "paper",  
            xanchor = "center",  
            yanchor = "bottom",  
            showarrow = F
          ),  
          list( 
            x = 0,  
            y = 0.425,  
            text = "c)",  
            xref = "paper",  
            yref = "paper",  
            xanchor = "center",  
            yanchor = "bottom",  
            showarrow = F
          ),
          list( 
            x = 0.6,  
            y = 0.425,  
            text = "d)",
            xref = "paper",  
            yref = "paper",  
            xanchor = "center",  
            yanchor = "bottom",  
            showarrow = F
          )))
}
```

You can find the data I am using here : https://drop.chapril.org/download/3a18d06ab9d7efe3/#rhJx3zXvPMWwfikWyIJaEQ

Comment: Please provide some sample data using `dput()` to make your code reproducible.

Comment: Sorry about that @Mandalorian I'm fixing it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't download all of that data. A small sample is usually more than enough. I created data; I used the same names, so this should migrate to your project pretty well.

I see that you had tried working with the `up` setting. You were close. You needed the `eye`. Depending on how you use this, it can cause you to zoom in and out, as well. So it's better to start small if you're not familiar with how it works.

My fake data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

dataresults1ab <- data.frame(time = 0:200) %>% 
  mutate(N1 = sin(time), N2 = cos(time), N3 = tan(time))
```

Figure B with your original code.

(Fig1b<-plot_ly(dataresults1ab, x = ~N1, y = ~N2, z = ~N3,
type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines")%>%
layout(title = "The corresponding limit cycle",
scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "Species 1", range = c(0,50)),
yaxis = list(title = "Species 2", range = c(0,50)),
zaxis = list(title = "Species 3", range = c(0,50)),
camera = list(up = list(0, 0.5, 0.5)))))

[image]

Modified figure B.

```
(Fig1b<-plot_ly(dataresults1ab, x = ~N1, y = ~N2, z = ~N3, 
                type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines")%>%
    layout(title = "The corresponding limit cycle",
           scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "Species 1", range = c(0,50)),
                        yaxis = list(title = "Species 2", range = c(0,50)),
                        zaxis = list(title = "Species 3", range = c(0,50)),
                        camera = list(eye = list(x = 2, y = 2, z = .1)))))
```

[image]

A slightly less aggressive adjustment of figure B.

```
(Fig1b<-plot_ly(dataresults1ab, x = ~N1, y = ~N2, z = ~N3, 
                type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines")%>%
    layout(title = "The corresponding limit cycle",
           scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "Species 1", range = c(0,50)),
                        yaxis = list(title = "Species 2", range = c(0,50)),
                        zaxis = list(title = "Species 3", range = c(0,50)),
                        camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.5, y = 1.5, z = .1)))))
```

[image]